# decide 1 or 2 or both grouped by 2 variables

Tags: r

**Question updated 9/10 !**

```
DF<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),rank=c("1","2","3","1","2","3"),code=c("A","B","B","B","B","A"))

DF
  id rank code
1  A1    1    A
2  A1    2    B
3  A1    3    B
4  B2    1    B
5  B2    2    B
6  B2    3    A
```

Desired output:

```
  id rank code type1 type2 type3
1  A1    1    A    aa   MIX   MIX
2  A1    2    B    NA   MIX   MIX
3  A1    3    B    NA    NA   MIX
4  B2    1    B    bb    bb   MIX
5  B2    2    B    NA    bb   MIX
6  B2    3    A    NA    NA   MIX
```

All is grouped by `id`

`type1` gets `code` where `rank` = 1.

`type2` gets `code` where `rank` = 1-2. If `code` is different in `rank` 1 and 2, then `MIX`

`type3` gets `code` where `rank` = 1-3. etc. etc.

Anyone? :)

Comment: You've edited your question to a different problem when you already had 4 answers to your previous question, rendering all 4 current answers invalid.

Comment: Sorry maybe that was a stupid move. I’ve posted it as a new question now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution using `ifelse` and a temporary column to reduce boilerplate:

```r
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(a = code[rank == 1],
         type1 = ifelse(rank > 1, NA, 
                        ifelse(all(code[!(rank > 1)] == a[1]), a[1], "MIX")),
         type2 = ifelse(rank > 2, NA, 
                        ifelse(all(code[!(rank > 2)] == a[1]), a[1], "MIX")),
         type3 = ifelse(rank > 3, NA, 
                        ifelse(all(code[!(rank > 3)] == a[1]), a[1], "MIX"))) %>%
  select(-a)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id rank  code  type1 type2 type3
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 1     A     A     MIX   MIX  
#> 2     1 2     B     NA    MIX   MIX  
#> 3     1 3     B     NA    NA    MIX  
#> 4     2 1     B     B     B     MIX  
#> 5     2 2     B     NA    B     MIX  
#> 6     2 3     A     NA    NA    MIX
```

Comment: When exectuting the code in my original data i get this error message: problem with ´mutate´, 'a' must be size 3 or 1, not 2. Why?

Comment: When executing your example I get this:

Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `type1`.
ℹ ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
ℹ Input `type1` is `ifelse(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: id = 1. 
2: Problem with `mutate()` input `type1`.

Comment: @hkolvs this suggests that your actual data is not in the same format as your example. Some of your ranks must be tied. Also, they appear to be factors rather than numbers. Try `DF$rank <- as.numeric(as.character(DF$rank))` first. Then change the first line of the `mutate` into `mutate(a = code[rank == 1][1],`

Comment: Thanks Allan, that solved the first problem. In my real dataset ID is character with both numbers and letters, which generates error message:

Comment: "result type for group 1" (ID) is double, "result type for group 73" (ID) is character.
I´ve tried to set ID as character but does not solve it! :( Is your code dependent of ID as numeric?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` with `case_when` statements:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(type2_grp = if_else(rank <= 2, 1, 0),
         type3_grp = if_else(rank <= 3, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(type1 = case_when(rank == 1 ~ code)) %>%
  group_by(id, type2_grp) %>%
  mutate(type2 = case_when(type2_grp == 1 & length(unique(code)) > 1 ~ "MIX",
                           type2_grp == 1 & code == "A" ~ "A",
                           type2_grp == 1 & code == "B" ~ "B")) %>%
  group_by(id, type3_grp) %>%
  mutate(type3 = case_when(type3_grp == 1 & length(unique(code)) > 1 ~ "MIX",
                           type3_grp == 1 & code == "A" ~ "A",
                           type3_grp == 1 & code == "B" ~ "B")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-type2_grp, -type3_grp)
```

Which creates:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     id rank  code  type1 type2 type3
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     A     A     MIX   MIX  
2     1 2     B     NA    MIX   MIX  
3     1 3     B     NA    NA    MIX  
4     2 1     B     B     B     MIX  
5     2 2     B     NA    B     MIX  
6     2 3     A     NA    NA    MIX
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution for an arbitrary number of "type" columns

```
maxtype=3

do.call(rbind,
  by(DF,list(DF$id),function(x){
    y=list()
    for (i in 1:maxtype) {
      tmp=rep(NA,nrow(x))
      idx=as.numeric(x$rank)<=i
      if (length(unique(x$code[idx]))==1) {
        tmp[idx]=x$code[1]
      } else {
        tmp[idx]="MIX"
      }
      y[[paste0("type",i)]]=tmp
    }
    cbind(x,y)
  })
)

    id rank code type1 type2 type3
1.1  1    1    A     A   MIX   MIX
1.2  1    2    B  <NA>   MIX   MIX
1.3  1    3    B  <NA>  <NA>   MIX
2.4  2    1    B     B     B   MIX
2.5  2    2    B  <NA>     B   MIX
2.6  2    3    A  <NA>  <NA>   MIX
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DF is sorted by `id` then `rank`, your `type` columns for each `id` will be an upper triangular matrix of "MIX" subset with an upper triangular matrix of the first `code` value for as many rows as it appears.

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),rank=c("1","2","3","1","2","3"),code=c("A","B","B","B","B","A"))
setDT(DF)[, `:=`(rank = factor(rank), code = factor(code))]

maxRank <- nlevels(DF$rank)
naLvl <- nlevels(DF$code) + 2L
mTri <- matrix(nlevels(DF$code) + 1L, nrow = maxRank, ncol = maxRank)
mTri[lower.tri(mTri)] <- naLvl

typeMat <- function(rank, code) {
  firstrep <- rle(code)[[1]][1]
  mSubTri <- matrix(naLvl, nrow = firstrep, ncol = firstrep)
  mSubTri[upper.tri(mSubTri, diag = TRUE)] <- code[1]
  mOut <- mTri
  mOut[1:firstrep, 1:firstrep] <- mSubTri
  return(mOut[rank,, drop = FALSE])
}

DF <- cbind(DF, as.data.table(do.call(rbind, DF[, (type = list(list(typeMat(as.integer(rank), as.integer(code))))), by = id]$V1)))
typeCols <- 4:(3 + maxRank)
DF[, (typeCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {factor(x, levels = 1:naLvl, labels = c(levels(code), "MIX", NA), exclude = NULL)}), .SDcols = typeCols]
setnames(DF, 4:(3 + maxRank), paste0("type", 1:maxRank))

> DF
   id rank code type1 type2 type3
1:  1    1    A     A   MIX   MIX
2:  1    2    B  <NA>   MIX   MIX
3:  1    3    B  <NA>  <NA>   MIX
4:  2    1    B     B     B   MIX
5:  2    2    B  <NA>     B   MIX
6:  2    3    A  <NA>  <NA>   MIX
```